# What's the difference between `yarn link` and `npm link`?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

Seems that sometimes `npm link` works in situations in which `yarn link` gives weird errors. I've noticed it a few times. I thought they were both making symlinks under the hood-- are they doing something different?

Comment: It would help if you post what weird behaviors you're seeing.

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco I'm not asking for help with a specific problem, just over the course of the past few months I've noticed that in different contexts they behave differently and I'd like to know where I can learn more about the difference between them.

Comment: This is true that they do not behave the same, sometimes `yarn link` just doesn't work while `npm link` does...

Comment: For anyone finding that `yarn link` doesn't add a symlink to the local binary (if you are developing a binary node app), that is because yarn link and `npm link` behave differently in that regard and it appears to be a known issue https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1585

Answer (score 5):

The yarn link and npm link mechanisms are different in the following ways:

- yarn creates a link directory at the same level as global, where all link softlinks are stored
- npm modifies the packaged files directly to one address in the public package management path /usr/local/lib/node_modules.

It is possible that the error message is related to yarn's path under generated links, or it could be something else, it still depends on the specific error message.

Answer (score 1):

[Yarn link simply does not work](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1297) even in the latest version (currently 4.0.2.)